# Laravel 4 Dynamic routing - Overkill?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We're in the process of setting up a Laravel 4 base project that we can work off of. I wanted to create a default routing rule that would allow developers could easily bang out new pages, without having to worry about adding routes to the controller, but making it so that other routes can be added for any more complicated routes/controllers.

I created the following routing rule, but I was wondering if it's overkill or not. I'm rather new to Laravel myself, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way or not, so I thought I'd post it and get some sort feedback on it.

```php
Route::any('{controller}/{action?}/{args?}', function($controller, $action = 'index', $args = '')
{
    $cont = "Controller";
    $notFound = "NotFound";
    $params = explode("/", $args);
    $app = app();

    if (!class_exists($controller.$cont) || !function_exists($contName.$cont.".".$action)) {
        $controller = $notFound;
        $action = 'index';
    }

    $controller = $app->make($controller.$cont);
    return $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], $action, $params);

 })
->where(array(
    'controller' => '[^/]+',
    'action' => '[^/]+',
    'args' => '[^?$]+'
));
```

Comment: Please write each route manually, you won't realize it's benefits until you start doing so.

Comment: I think what you've outlined here is definitely overkill. It's not that difficult to add another route and doing so has numerous benefits.

Answer (score 5):

If you have about 5 routes then it doesn't make much sense to do this, however if you have plenty of routes that will follow this pattern it is makes much sense. Just make sure you test your code so it won't break in production.

By the way .NET MVC maps default routes very similar to how you do it which makes it very convenient since you don't have to map every route manually. So I guess it is completely normal.